# kube-apiserver on OpenShift

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, kube-apiserver

I'm new to OpenShift and Kubernetes.

I need to access kube-apiserver on existing OpenShift environment

```
oc v3.10.0+0c4577e-1
kubernetes v1.10.0+b81c8f8
```

how do I know kube-apiserver is already installed, or how to get it installed?

I checked all the containers and there is no even such path /etc/kubernetes/manifests.

Here is the list of docker processes on all clusters, could it hide behind one of these?

`k8s_fluentd-elasticseark8s_POD_logging
k8s_POD_tiller-deploy
k8s_api_master-api-ip-...ec2.internal_kube-system
k8s_etcd_master-etcd-...ec2.internal_kube-system
k8s_POD_master-controllers
k8s_POD_master-api-ip-
k8s_POD_kube-state
k8s_kube-rbac-proxy
k8s_POD_node-exporter
k8s_alertmanager-proxy
k8s_config-reloader
k8s_POD_alertmanager_openshift-monitoring
k8s_POD_prometheus
k8s_POD_cluster-monitoring
k8s_POD_heapster
k8s_POD_prometheus
k8s_POD_webconsole
k8s_openvswitch
k8s_POD_openshift-sdn
k8s_POD_sync
k8s_POD_master-etcd`

Comment: What are you wanting to access it with, ``oc``, ``kubectl``, REST API? If I understand what is meant by the API server, it should always be enabled. What information do you have about how to access the cluster?

Comment: I need to run CIS Kubernetis benchmark to verify the secure configuration. The main command is 'ps -ef | grep kube-apiserver'

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to verify that the cluster is up and running then you can simply run `oc get nodes` which communicates with the kube-apiserver to retrieve information.

`oc config view` will show where kube-apiserver is hosted under the clusters -> cluster -> server section. On that host machine you can run command `docker ps` to display the running containers, which should include the kube-apiserver

Comment: thanks, but still can't see. could it have some weird name in my case?

(added the output list into the top question)

Comment: looks like I found what I need here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33953254/what-is-hyperkube, /usr/bin/hyperkube kubelet is running all other modules in my environment